# OrbitControls and dat.gui text doesn't work

Tags: javascript, three.js, dat.gui

I am using three.js and dat.gui with a **text** property.

Also, I have OrbitControls in my scene:

`cameraControl = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera);
cameraControl.update();`

But there is a problem with this kind of scene. **The text at the GUI doesn't work**. You can't type anything in that box. And I have debugged it, and the problem is caused by OrbitControls.

Do you know a way or workaround to solve it? Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to pass the dom element you want to listen the events from.

```
cameraControl = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera,renderer.domElement);
```

Otherwise `OrbitControls` adds the events to the document and that conflicts with DAT.GUI.